# How can I reduce the bass in Xubuntu 16.04 *without* using software from a third-party repo?

Tags: sound, xubuntu

What sound equaliser or bass-reduction software is available for Xubuntu 16.04 that doesn't require adding a third-party repository?

I've been through multiple Stack Exchange questions, forum posts, etc and spent at least two hours on this. Most of the answers involve adding a custom Launchpad repo or installing software from GitHub, however in my particular situation this is not an option.

So far I've tried the alsamixer 'equal' plugin, however this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Maybe this - https://askubuntu.com/a/910010/29073 will help. Or use PulseEffects, https://askubuntu.com/a/954604/29073.

Comment: @pbhj Unfortunately it seems that both of those suggestions require adding a ppa, which I am unfortunately unable to do.

Comment: Is it no installation, or no ppas? You can download the packages, eg with a browser or wget,  install with `sudo dpkg -i $package`

Comment: It's no third-party software. I.e. it has to be from the official, built-in repos or a local config file, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see, pulseaudio-equaliser (first link above) is official in 17.10+ (though somewhere said it was 17.04; https://packages.ubuntu.com disagrees). If it's a political restriction then maybe you could spin it as that's a download from Canonical. I'd look at jackd, but you'd probably want a LADSPA plugin or something that's possibly not going to be on the official servers.