# PulseEffects is broken

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

(Im running 18.04)

I followed a tutorial from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1076445/1009141

I now have bass boost. Yay!

Sadly, I tried tweaking around with my individual app's sound in the Pulseaudio app. Now, my volume control in my notification thing at the top doesnt do anything anymore.

Also, when I use the +sound shortcut on my keyboard, i see that ubuntu is raising the volume of a device called "PulseEffects(mic)".

How can I make it so im able to control the sound volume again, using the volume rocker in my notification thing?

Comment: Also sorry if im not clear, english isnt my first language.

Comment: 18.04. also, while trying to purge configuration files for pulseeffects i dont have sound anymore. lol

Comment: nevermind, fixed it by reinstalling the recommended packages for pulseeffects. @guiverc

Comment: Still, my problem is not solved. Please help.